# Adding style in $refs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Can't add style in $refs attribute. Cannot set property 'cssText' of undefined. Is this possible? Can't find any similar to this

```
this.$refs['ticketCode_'+this.resoTrans_id].style.cssText =
                "background-color:#66BB6A !important; border:1px solid #66BB6A !important; color:#fff !important;";
```

Printing out without .style seems work fine `console.log(this.$refs['ticketCode_'+this.resoTrans_id])`

```
VueComponent {_uid: 493, _isVue: true, $options:
```

Answer (score 22):

You're not supposed to use cssText but instead use the JavaScript API to set styles (which you can do on $refs, too):

```
let $ref = this.$refs['ticketCode_' + this.resoTrans_id]

$ref.style.backgroundColor = '#66bb6a';
$ref.style.border = '1px solid #66bb6a';
...
```

Even better is to utilize Vue's power for that directly in your template:

```
<your-element ref="'ticketCode_' + resoTrans_id" :style="{ backgroundColor: '#66bb6a', border: '1px solid #66bb6a' /* ... */ }" />
```

Comment: I get this error in Vue 3 composition API with a `let myPopup = ref<HTMLDivElement>();`..

I get this error: Invalid left-hand side in assignment expression

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the style on the $ref's element property, $el. Your $ref itself is a Vue Component (as described by your $ref's console output), not an HTML element:

```
this.$refs['ref-name'].$el.style.top = `${topVal}px`
```

Answer (score 0):

apply directly $refs.objectkey style

```
this.$refs['ticketCode_' + this.resoTrans_id].style.background="red"
```